# elementary proof that infinite primes quadratic residue modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-reciprocity, quadratic-residues

$p \gt 2$ is a prime, then  there are infinite primes $q$  such that $q$  is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

With [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), the problem is  easy! How about  **Without** the use of the theorem? Can one find  an elementary proof?

p.s.  there are  several  elementary ways(without Dirichlet) to show that there are infinite primes $q$  such that $q$  is a quadratic **non-residue** modulo $p$

Proof 1  The least $q>0$ quadratic non-residue modulo $p$  is a prime . Consider

$$a_0=q, a_1=q+p,a_2=q+pa_1,a_3=q+pa_1a_2,\dotsc, a_n=q+pa_1a_2\dotsb a_{n-1},\dotsc $$
then $(a_i,a_j)=1$

Proof 2  Only $\dfrac{p-1}2$ quadratic non-residues modulo $p$, so there is a integer $a$ such that $(\dfrac{a^2+1}p)=-1$.

In not, only finite $q_1,q_2,\dotsc, q_n$. then there exists $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $kq_1q_2\dotsb q_n \equiv a \pmod p$. Consider

$$ (kq_1q_2\dotsb q_n)^2 +1$$

Comment: also, you asked the same thing yesterday and then deleted.

Comment: @WillJagy two elementary proofs add

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given **ODD** primes $p \neq q:$ and $$ \color{magenta}{p \equiv 3 \pmod 4}  $$

Lemma:  $$ (-p|q) = (q|p). $$

Lemma: If $$ a^2 + p \equiv 0 \pmod q,  $$ THEN  $$ (q|p) = 1. $$

Let $$ F_1 = 4 + p,  $$
$$ F_2 = 4 F_1^2 + p,  $$
$$ F_3 = 4 F_1^2 F_2^2 + p,  $$
$$ F_4 = 4 F_1^2 F_2^2 F_3^2 + p,  $$
$$ F_5 = 4 F_1^2 F_2^2 F_3^2 F_4^2 + p,  $$
and so on.

These are all of the form $a^2 + p$ and are odd, so the only primes than can be factors are quadratic residues for $p.$ Next, all the $F_j$ are prime to $p$ itself. Finally, these are all coprime. So, however they factor, we get an infinite list of primes that are quadratic residues of $p.$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Given **ODD** primes $p \neq q:$ and $$ \color{magenta}{p \equiv 1 \pmod 4}  $$

Lemma:  $$ (p|q) = (q|p). $$

Lemma: If $$ a^2 - p \equiv 0 \pmod q,  $$ THEN  $$ (q|p) = 1. $$

FIND an even square $$ W = 4^k = \left( 2^k \right)^2 $$ such that
$$  \color{magenta}{ W > p.}  $$

Let $$ F_1 = W - p,  $$
$$ F_2 = W F_1^2 - p,  $$
$$ F_3 = W F_1^2 F_2^2 - p,  $$
$$ F_4 = W F_1^2 F_2^2 F_3^2 - p,  $$
$$ F_5 = W F_1^2 F_2^2 F_3^2 F_4^2 - p,  $$
and so on. As $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $W \equiv 0 \pmod 4,$ we know $W - p \equiv 3 \pmod 4 $ and so  $W-p \geq 3. $ So the $F_j$ are larger than $1$ and strictly increasing.

These are all of the form $a^2 - p$ and are odd, so the only primes than can be factors are quadratic residues for $p.$ Next, all the $F_j$ are prime to $p$ itself. Finally, these are all coprime. So, however they factor, we get an infinite list of primes that are quadratic residues of $p.$

Answer (score 5):

By quadratic reciprocity, $(p/q) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2}(-1)^{(q-1)/2}(q/p)$.

Let $\chi$ be the Dirichlet character of conductor $4p$ given by $n \mapsto (-1)^{(n-1)/2}(n/p)$.

Then the function $q \mapsto (q/p)$ is nothing but $q \mapsto (-1)^{(p-1)/2}\chi(q)$, almost a Dirichlet character (it is a Dirichlet character if $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and minus a Dirichlet character if $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$).

The character $\chi$ determines the splitting of primes in the quadratic field $K=\mathbf Q(\sqrt{p^*})$, where $p^* = (-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$. More precisely, the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(s)$ factors as
$$\zeta_K(s) = \zeta(s)L(\chi,s).$$
An easy estimate shows that the Dedekind zeta function of any number field has a simple pole at $s=1$. Since $\zeta(s)$ has a simple pole there, it must be the case that $L(\chi,1)\neq 0, \infty$, in other words the series

$$0<\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n}\right| <\infty.$$

By the divergence of the harmonic series this implies that there are infinitely many $n$ with $\chi(n)=1$ and infinitely many $n$ with $\chi(n)=-1$ (and that they are evenly distributed enough so that the series converges). Using the Euler product, we see also that there are infinitely many primes with $\chi(q)=1$ and infinitely many primes with $\chi(q)=-1$.

**Remark**: This is basically a proof of a very primitive version of Cebotarev's theorem in this very specific case.