# Legendre symbol and variable denominator

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

Suppose $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and let $p$ be a prime, such that $p>>z$. Can I say something what happens to Legendre symbol $(\frac{z}{p})$ if I vary $p$?

One obvious answer comes when $x^2=z$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, namely $(\frac{z}{p})=1$ for $p$ big enough. Suppose now that $z$ is prime. Are sets:
\begin{equation*}
S_+(z)=\{\,p\;|\;(\frac{z}{p})=1\}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
S_-(z)=\{\,p\;|\;(\frac{z}{p})=-1\}
\end{equation*}
of infinite cardinality?

Comment: Your sets depend on a given $z$? So $S_+(z)$ and $S_-(z)$? For $z=1$ the set $S_+(1)$ is infinite, but the set $S_-(1)$ is empty.

Comment: You are right of course. I have corrected it.

Comment: For $z=2$ we know that $(2/p)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$, so both sets are infinite. This will also happen for all $z\ge 2$ because of [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226563/infinitely-many-primes-for-quadratic-residues).

Comment: I see, that it solves the case of $S_+(z)$, but how does it help with $S_-(z)$?

Comment: It is the same idea for $S_-(z)$, see Bruno's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748571/elementary-proof-that-infinite-primes-quadratic-residue-modulo-p).

Comment: I think, I have understood it. Thank you for your time and attention.